# PHP Help for showing results differently for top 3 results and the remaining 7 default all look the same

Tags: php

I want to make something that for the first result it will show something unique than the rest and 2nd and 3rd place will look a bit different too and then the last 7 results will all just show in the same format as stated below, how would I go about doing that to this form of code?

```
<?php
$evenOdd = 'even';
$user_a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank < 4 ORDER BY credits             DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($users = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_a)) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '" . $users['id'] . "' LIMIT 10"));
    $online = $row['online'];
    if ($evenOdd == 'even') {
        $evenOdd = 'odd';
    } else {
        $evenOdd = 'even';
    }
    if ($online == 0) {
        $aanwezig = "<img   src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/site/images/icons/offline.gif'/>";
    } else {
        $aanwezig = "<img src='http://localhost/app/tpl/skins/site/images/icons/online.gif'/>";
    }
    echo '
    <a href="http://localhost/home/' . $row['username'] . '"><div class="head-' . $evenOdd . '" style="background-image: url(https://avatar-retro.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=' . $row['look'] . '&headonly=1&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=s);"></div>
    <div class="username-' . $evenOdd . '">' . $row['username'] . '' . $aanwezig . '</a></div>
    <div class="stat-' . $evenOdd . '"><b><font size="2">' . number($row['credits']) . '</b></font> <font size="1">Credits</font></div>
    ';
}       
?>
```

I have another code that does a similar thing from a friend but I can't figure it out for how to implement it into my code because his is coded a bit differently from my own

```
public function topCredits() {
    $content = '';
    $users = MangoEngine::$object['users']->find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank < 2 ORDER BY credits DESC LIMIT 5");
    $odd = '';
    $first = true;
    $num = 0;
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $num++;
        if($odd == "background-color:#fff;") {
            $odd = "background-color:#ECECEC;border-top:1px dashed #CCCCCC;border-bottom:1px dashed #CCCCCC;";
        } else {
            $odd = "background-color:#fff;";
        }
        $content .= "<table width=\"102%\" height=\"60px\" style=\"margin-left:-3px;{$odd}\">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td valign=\"middle\" width=\"25\" height=\"50px\">";
                if($first) {
                    $content .= "<img style=\"margin-top:-100px;margin-bottom:-10px;\" src=\"{$user->getFigure("&amp;gesture=sml&amp;direction=2&amp;size=sml")} \" />";
                } else {
                    $content .= "<img style=\"margin-top:-10px;margin-bottom:-10px;\" src=\"{$user->getFigure("&amp;headonly=1&amp;gesture=sml&amp;direction=2&amp;size=sml")} \" />";
                }
                $content .= "</td>
                <td valign=\"top\">
                    <p style=\"margin-top:5px;\"><strong><a style=\"color:black;\" href=\"/home/{$user->username}\">{$user->username}</a></strong></p>
                    <p style=\"margin-top:-7px;\"><font color=\"grey\">" . MangoCore::shortNumber($user->credits) . " %creditsAmount%</font></p>";
                    if($num == 1) {
                        $content .= "<img style=\"float:right;margin-top:-35px;margin-right:10px;\" src=\"/Mango/skins/Default/images/stats/gold.png\" />";
                    } else if($num == 2) {
                        $content .= "<img style=\"float:right;margin-top:-35px;margin-right:10px;\" src=\"/Mango/skins/Default/images/stats/silver.png\" />";
                    } else if($num == 3) {
                        $content .= "<img style=\"float:right;margin-top:-35px;margin-right:10px;\" src=\"/Mango/skins/Default/images/stats/bronze.png\" />";
                    } else {

                    }
                $content .= "</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>";
        $first = false;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Why not make use of CSS for this, ideally I'd recommend using the `:nth-child()` selectors

Comment: Im quite new to coding so Im not really familar with everything

Comment: dont use mysql_* functions they are deprecated and insecure also removed in php7. use mysqli or better pdo. as said use html/css as Dale said if you dont know its time to learn that first. as your output relay on that

Comment: I use MySQL because Im on php 5 and the CMS im using is all ran on MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by implementing a counter in your loop for rows as shown in second code by '$num'.
You will be having three condition in your case.

```
if($num==1) else
if($num ==2 || $num ==3)else
if($num >3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the following tables being out put in a php loop

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some data</td>
        <td>Some more data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some data</td>
        <td>Some more data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some data</td>
        <td>Some more data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some data</td>
        <td>Some more data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Some data</td>
        <td>Some more data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can make use of CSS to style the tables and avoid having the code mixed in with your server side!

```
<style>
    /* default table styles */
    table {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: 'Open sans', arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    /* overridden styles for first three tables */
    table:nth-of-type(1),
    table:nth-of-type(2),
    table:nth-child(3) {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

It's also quite possible that there is a much nicer selector for the tables too, I just can't think of one :)